# Chi-squared test for data with error bars

Tags: python, chi-squared, errorbar

Suppose I have two arrays, `A1` and `A2`:

```
A1 = [1,2,2,2,3,3,7]
A2 = [0.5,1,1.5,2,7,2,6.9]
```

Suppose I also have the error bar data for `A1`:

```
err_bars = [0.1,0.6,0.9,0.2,0.01,0.8,0.1]
```

I want to see if there is a way to determine if the data in `A2` fits with that in `A1`.

Is there any way to calculate the Chi-squared, F-test and *p*-value considering the error bars in the data?

So far I could not find any Chi-squared function in Python that considers the error bars of the data.

Comment: can u pls elaborate ur question..?

Comment: Maybe update your question with a solution to the case that doesn't consider the errors.

Comment: This question is off topic. It should be moved to crossvalidated. You are asking how to compute a goodness of fit or least squares statistic that considers the observations' errors. You are not asking a specific programming question.

Comment: What I'm asking is that chisquared can also be calculated considering the error bars in the observed data (here A1) which is given as (A1[i]-A2[i])^2/(err_bars[i])^2. But al i could find in python was the ones considering no error bars in the data; such as scipy.stats.chisquare.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   # obs -- observed value
    # exp -- expected value

def chisqr(obs, exp, error):
    chisqr = 0
    for i in range(len(obs)):
        chisqr = chisqr + ((obs[i]-exp[i])**2)/(error[i]**2)
    return chisqr

A1 = [1,2,2,2,3,3,7]
A2 = [0.5,1,1.5,2,7,2,6.9]
err_bars = [0.1,0.6,0.9,0.2,0.01,0.8,0.1]
print chisqr(A1, A2, err_bars)
```

Comment: But even here the err_bars are not considered.

Comment: let me update the code based on the formula you provided.

Comment: I have updated the code based on the formula you have provided. Take a look.

Comment: Then how can I get the pvalue?

Comment: you can use this code as a starting point and modify the formula and function to define p-value function. I don't know the formula to calculate p-value, as i am not statistician.I would definitely recommend you to read python documentation, particularly how to define a function. good luck!

Comment: @shadi - Please mark this as answered as this addresses your concern.

Answer (score 1):

If your working with numerical data, chances are you should be using the `numpy` package to do most of your calculations. For anything more than a small calculation its significantly faster, and its almost always easier to read (A good summery why is [here](https://webcourses.ucf.edu/courses/1249560/pages/python-lists-vs-numpy-arrays-what-is-the-difference)). Switching to to `numpy` lets you write this as

```py
A1 = np.array([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7])
A2 = np.array([0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 7, 2, 6.9])
err_bars = np.array([0.1, 0.6, 0.9, 0.2, 0.01, 0.8, 0.1])

def chisq(obs, exp, error):
    return np.sum((obs - exp) ** 2 / (error ** 2))

print(chisq(A1, A2, err_bars))
```